# Как сделать форму для скрипта?

Tags: post, php, форма

Я PHP только начинаю изучать, поэтому не пинайте и не ругайте меня. Вот скрипт:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
//-----------------//
$komy = "Alex";
$otkogo = "test";
$msg = "hello word";
//-----------------//

/* Кидаем смс-ку */
$ch = curl_init("http://***********.ru/ccc-php/sms/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/2008102920 AdCentriaIM/1.7 Firefox/3.0.4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "action=send&msisdn=".urlencode($komy)."&from=".urlencode($otkogo)."&msg=".urlencode($msg)."&submit=Send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://*********.ru/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "./cook");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$res_index  = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы форму можно было заполнять на сайте, а не в самом скрипте? Я как только не делал, у меня не ничего не получалось.

Comment: Коментарии к коду жгут ...

Comment: я про:

    /* Ебошим смс-ку */

> Я как только не делал - у меня не ничего не получалось
по кофейной гуще не гадаю и на такие вопросы не отвечаю. Что именно не получилось ? Почему ? Как по мне - так я не вижу никаких проблем, тем более вменяемый ответ уже был дан: @Node_pro

Comment: форму нужно сделать в одном скрипте, так то скрипт отправляет. но хотелось бы через форму :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $komy = "Alex";
 $otkogo = "test";
```

Первое, что хочу сказать, - завязывайте с такими именами переменных. Их можно было бы обозвать $to и $from или $recipient и $sender. Но не транслитом.

Ну, а с формой всё просто. Натравливаете атрибут формы action на свой скрипт и после сабмита получаете все данные от этой формы в массиве $_POST. С ним и работаете.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется здесь работа для html

```
<form action="name.php">
 <p><b>**Название пункта**:</b></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="**имя поля**" value="**по умолчанию**"> **Инфо**<Br/></p>
<p><b>**Название пункта**:</b></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="**имя поля**" value="**по умолчанию**"> **Инфо**<Br/></p>
<p><b>**Название пункта:**</b></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="**имя поля**" value="**по умолчанию**">**Инфо**<Br/></p>
</form>
```

name.php - файл обработки
тест помечен   - тут Вам надо подставить свои данные
В файле **name.php**
Выводим переменные с урла браузера

```
<?
    $имя поля = $_POST['имя поля'];
    $имя поля = $_POST['имя поля'];
    $имя поля = $_POST['имя поля'];
    ...
?>
```

**//Не забудьте заменить "имя поля"**

Если Вы обращаетесь ко мне то говорите конкретнее какие формы Вам надо или пишите в скайп node_xaker помогу, чтобы на форуме не мусорить

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь достаточно подробно описаны [сценарии с формами на php](http://in-internet.narod.ru/teor/phpform.html).

**Приблизительно так:**

```
<form method=POST>
    Кому: <input type='text' name='komu'><br>
    От кого: <input type='text' name='otkogo'><br>
    Сообщение: <input type='text' name="msg"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

**Это вписать в текст перед скриптом**.

А это заменить вместо

```
$komy = "Alex";
$otkogo = "test";
$msg = "hello word";
```

на это

```
$komy = $_POST['komu'];
$otkogo = $_POST['otkogo'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое!!! все работает, единственное пишет в самом вверху:

Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in /var/www/root/data/www/*********.ru/script/index.php on line 2

Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /var/www/root/data/www/*********.ru/script/index.php on line 17

не знаете в чем проблема? а так отправляет

Comment: Самое простое решение поставить перед curl_setopt() "@"
@curl_setopt()
@set_time_limit() 
Но это просто скроет ошибку

Comment: что-то не получается..